# batch script to copy files from one folder to another that contain particular strings

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Hi i am using this batch script to copy files from one folder to another based on a condition that if it contains a particular string,the script is :

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /l /e /y "C:\Users\abc\abcd\abcde\abcdef\*abc*.pdf" "c:\test\" ^|find ":"') do copy "%%a" "C:\Users\abc\abcd\abcde\abcdef\copyfiles"
```

When i run the script,though it runs successfully ,but instead of creating a new folder a new file with unknown extension is created with the name `copyfiles`

Where am i going wrong in this?Sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Every line will contain `:` right?

But to solve the copy problem, the folder needs to exist in advance.